# Bernoulli Naive Bayes error: ValueError: Unknown label type: (array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=object),)

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, naivebayes

I have two numpy arrays x and y acquired from an sframe where x has 6 dimensions and y (target variable) has one dimension.

```
x =np.array([[ 0 , 0 , 0, 24 ,0, 34], [ 0 , 0 , 0, 22 ,0, 34], ...])
y = np.array([[0], [0], [0], [1], [1], ...])
```

I am using scikit-learn to apply naive bayes classifier. When I try to fit x and y in naive bayes classifier, I gives the following error:

```
/home/.../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:526: DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().

      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_naive.py", line 10, in <module>
    main()
  File "main_naive.py", line 7, in main
    naive_bayes.predict()
  File "/home/.../naive_bayes_model.py", line 184, in predict
    self.naive_bayes.fit(x, y)
  File "/home/.../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py", line 566, in fit
    Y = labelbin.fit_transform(y)
  File "/home/.../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 494, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
  File "/home/.../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py", line 304, in fit
    self.classes_ = unique_labels(y)
  File "/home/.../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py", line 98, in unique_labels
    raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %s" % repr(ys))
ValueError: Unknown label type: (array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=object),)
```

Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
naive_bayes = BernoulliNB(alpha=1e-2)
#x = self.training1[self.feature_columns].to_numpy()
#x = x.reshape(-len(self.feature_columns), len(self.feature_columns))
#y = self.training1[[target_column]].to_numpy()
#y = y.reshape(-1L,1L)    
x =np.array([[ 0 , 0 , 0, 24 ,0, 34], [ 0 , 0 , 0, 22 ,0, 34], ...])
y = np.array([[0], [0], [0], [1], [1], ...])    
naive_bayes.fit(x, y)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Posting complete stack trace should almost always help you get answers quicker. Also the code you've posted is definitely different that something you have (it's guaranteed not to work in its current state).

Comment: I lack mathematical knowledge of this, but now when I run your code, I get a different error, suggesting that perhaps this method is designed for arrays of same dimensions.

Comment: Your arrays are the wrong shape, you have a 2 x 6 array and a 6 x 1 array. In `scikit` the input is (n_samples, n_features)

Comment: Both `x` and `y` are actually 2d. `naive_bayes.fit` expects `y` to be 1d. That's probably the source of the error.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. It was because y contained 'None' values, so I simply removed None values from y.